# What is the effect of using different COLLATE values in a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, collation

I read the documentation 'Using COLLATE in SQL Statements' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collate.html, but it doesn't say much about the effect of using different COLLATE values to the examples. Just as an example,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE k LIKE _latin1 'Müller' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
```

What's the difference between using different values after `COLLATE`? What about if not using the `COLLATE` clause at all? How does one find the right or possible values to use after `COLLATE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or...  The Optimizer would not be able to use an index.

It is best (for performance) for everything to have the same collation:

- The column
- The connection
- The client

Having to switch collations 'at run time' is costly.

Or, I use it to see how different collations handle accents, etc.

Note that an index has the data stored in a given character set and collation.  Any need to deviate from that eliminates the ability to use the index for performance.

Answer (score 2):

it would make both sides have the same collation, when the databse can't compare the data and gives following error or similar ones

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' ....

And there is also to possibility to make a cs (case  sensitive 'ABC is not eual to 'abc') to a ci case insensitive comparisons so 'ABC' would equal 'abc' or vice versa